# How to use a string in a symbolic expression with SageMath?

Tags: sagemath

I would like to use a string as part of a symbolic expression. 
For instance:

```
function('P')
var('x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3')
st = eval('y1,0,1')
sum(P(x1,y1,y2,y3),st)
```

How could I use st which is a string in the symbolic expression sum?

I want the same result as if I had typed directly:

```
sum(P(x1,y1,y2,y3),y1,0,1)
```

Comment: This isn't really a question about mathematics, so I am voting to close.

Comment: More appropriate for https://ask.sagemath.org

Comment: It is a question on SageMath

Comment: since sage math is a valid label for a question in SE mathematics it would seem reasonable that a question about sage is a valid question

Answer (score 0):

Define a symbolic function `P` and some symbolic variables:

```
sage: P = function('P')
sage: x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3 = SR.var('x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3')
```

Define a triple (using a string and the `eval` function)

```
sage: st = eval('y1, 0, 1')
sage: st
(y1, 0, 1)
```

The question of how to attain the same result as

```
sage: sum(P(x1, y1, y2, y3), y1, 0, 1)
P(x1, 1, y2, y3) + P(x1, 0, y2, y3)
```

by using `st` is not really about how to use a string,
since `st` is now a triple.

The required operation is called unpacking a tuple.

In Python, unpacking any iterable is achieved using `*`:

```
sage: sum(P(x1, y1, y2, y3), *st)
P(x1, 1, y2, y3) + P(x1, 0, y2, y3)
```